# "Choices" in R-Shiny to pull a column form a table placed in RMySQL

Tags: r, shiny

I've a table "table1" in MySQL with columns "name" and "address". Now I am developing R-Shiny module to show a drop-down with list of all names (unique) present in that table. Can someone help with the code.

Need to understand how choices = table1$name works, because to me it's giving error as 'object table1 not found'. Pls help..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to establish a connection between MySQL and R Studio.

```
sqlQuery <- function (query) {

  # creating DB connection object with RMysql package
  DB <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='username', password='pass', dbname='databasename', host='localhost')

  # send Query to obtain result set

    rs <- dbSendQuery(DB, query)

  # get elements from result sets and convert to data frame
  result <- fetch(rs, -1)

  # to close resultset in RMySQL
  dbClearResult(dbListResults(DB)[[1]])

  # close db connection after function call exits
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(DB), add = FALSE)

  # return the dataframe
  return(result)
}
```

shiny dashboard web app

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody( 
   uiOutput("firstSelection")  
  )
)
mydata <- sqlQuery("select name, address from table1")
server <- function(input, output) { 

output$secondSelection <- renderUI({

selectInput("name", "Select Name", choices = mydata$name)

}) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```